# Order of values in dfs and bfs

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Let's consider a matrix of integers `m`:

```py
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]]
```

Which represents a graph:

```
    (1)
    / \
  (4) (2)
  / \ / \
(7) (5) (3)
 \ /  \ / 
  (8) (6)
    \ /
    (9)
```

There are two implementations of traversals `bfs` and `dfs`.
BFS uses `queue`, DFS uses `stack`, since there is no `stack` data structure in python both could be implemented using simple `list`or any other arbitrarily chosen data structure, which behaves like a `queue` and `stack` respectively, I opted for `deque`.

```py
def bfs_iterative(matrix, i, j, visited=None):
    if not matrix:
        return
    values = [matrix[i][j]]
    rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    visited = visited if visited else set()
 
    queue = deque([(i, j)])
    visited.add((i, j))
    directions = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]
    while queue:
        row, col = queue.popleft()
        for dr, dc in directions:
            r, c = row + dr, col + dc
            if r not in range(rows):
                continue
            if c not in range(cols):
                continue
            if (r, c) in visited:
                continue
            queue.append((r, c))
            visited.add((r, c))
            values.append(matrix[r][c])
    return values
 
 
 
def dfs_iterative(matrix, i, j, visited=None):
    if not matrix:
        return
    values = []
    rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    visited = visited if visited else set()
 
    stack = deque()
    stack.append((i, j))
    directions = [
        (0, -1),
        (0, 1),
        (-1, 0),
        (1, 0),
    ]
    while stack:
        row, col = stack.pop()
        if (row, col) not in visited:
            visited.add((row, col))
            values.append(matrix[row][col])
 
        for dr, dc in directions:
            r, c = row + dr, col + dc
            if r not in range(rows):
                continue
            if c not in range(cols):
                continue
            if (r, c) in visited:
                continue
            stack.append((r, c))
 
    return values
```

Depending on the order of directions in `bfs` the output of the values will be:
[1,4,2,7,5,3,8,6,9] or [1,2,4,3,5,7,6,8,9], which probably doesn't matter since "levels" are diagonals and the levels are in correct order (top to down), the elements are left to right or right to left.
But for `dfs` there are more possible outputs and I wonder whether my implementation is off or each of those outputs is correct. Since for `BST` there are in-order, post-order, pre-order traversals and each is valid and each is `dfs` I think the 2nd option, but I cannot find a decent read about that actually.
Found [A BFS and DFS implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221534/a-bfs-and-dfs-implementation) which sort of tackles this question.

Comment: I think you mixed up "bfs" and "dfs" in the last paragraph. A bfs searches a "level" before it goes to a deeper level. A dfs keeps going deeper until it can't go any deeper, then backs up until it finds a different path to try.

Comment: Right, fixed that

Answer (score 1):

## Visited?

What is the point of `visited=None` in your function signatures?  It looks like you're setting up for a recursive call, where the standard caller doesn't provide a `visited` argument, but the recursive call needs to pass it in.

You could omit the argument, and simply write `visited = set()` in the bodies of the functions.

Or are you allowing the caller to provide a collection of locations which shouldn't be visited?  In which case, do you really want that collection to be modified by your function?  Maybe you want:

```
    visited = set(visited) if visited else set()
```

to a) make a copy you can freely modified, and b) ensure the collection they've given you is actually an \$O(1)\$ set.

## Optional[list[int]]

The `if not matrix: return` complicates your function.  Instead of your functions returning a `list[int]`, they return the more complicated `Optional[list[int]]`.

If the matrix is empty, using `return []` keeps your return type consistent.

## Ranges

```
    rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    ...
    while queue:
        ...
        for dr, dc in directions:
            if r not in range(rows):
                continue
            if c not in range(cols):
                continue
```

Pop quiz: given a 9x11 matrix, how many `range()` objects are created?  How many *unique* `range()` objects did you actually need?

How about:

```
    rows = range(len(matrix))
    cols = range(len(matrix[0]))
    ...

    while queue:
        ...
        for dr, dc in directions:
            if r not in rows:
                continue
            if c not in cols:
                continue
```

## BFS Loop rerolling

Consider 1 of the initial lines, and 1 of the last lines of your loop:

```
    values = [matrix[i][j]]
    ...
            ...
            values.append(matrix[r][c])
```

In addition to creating the `values` structure, the first  statements is adding  `matrix[r][c]` to that structures ... assume `i, j = r, c` that is.  It looks like you've primed your loop wrong, causing you to need to replicate the logic in both places.

In the DFS, you append to `values` just after you visit (pop) `(row, col)` off the `stack`.  You can do the same thing here:

```
    values = []
    visited = {(i, j)}
    queue = deque([(i, j)])

    while queue:
        row, col = queue.popleft()
        values.append(matrix[r][c])

        for dr, dc in directions:
            r, c = row + dr, col + dc
            if r in rows and c in cols and (r, c) not in visited:
                visited.add((r, c))
                queue.append((r, c))
```

Comment: Visited - not sure I want to allocate memory for that possibly huge `set` if I don't want to do if for pretty small `range` objects, do I? 
Optional - yeah, that's true, didn't type hint, didn't notice, good point.
Pop quiz: 0...I need literally **0** range objects, cause I could just `if r<0 or r>rows-1` 
I guess `values.append(matrix[r][c])` should be `values.append(matrix[row][col])`, cause `r` and `c` are not defined in this scope, right? It is redundant, I agree, however not sure what do you mean by "wrong" tbh and what logic is replicated, I'll give it a 2nd look though.
Thanks :)